# Using a tour to show how to use the dashboard?

Tags: dashboard

Tours can show steps to users for enabling them to use the dashboard stepwise or just get to know where to find things you need.
But still how important it is?-

Comment: It doesn't have to be an issue if it's a complex application that's hard to make any easier. But if you want more elaborate answers, please provide more details on your particular situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can design your application dashboard so easily and friendly ,with simplifying and elimination any unnecessary items,your user may not need tour for understating application flow.
Ask these question yourself before deciding to use tour:

Is my feeling that users need tour, because:

- My Application don't cover essential need and user don't know for doing what coming in.
- My Application Dashboard covers multiple task and flow in single GUI so user would be confused.
- My GUI items and steps aren't sorted and grouped truly so user may be confused what to do first and what ,second.
- It,s not clear for them where to find something.

If no one is true ,it's time to use user guide tour.
for deciding to select what kind of tour is appropriated for your project , ask yourself these questions,Do I need in my tour steps and popup to :

- Navigate user in multiple pages?
- Show link or button?
- Show inputs and controls?
- Show image?
- Show Number or title of step?
- Show progress bar?
- Acting user in page , change steps flow?
- Canceling next steps of tour?
- Need to enter sample data in inputs?
- Need to save user state? Showing only in first time? which steps were shown and witch ones not?

Answer (score 0):

A walkthrough is the process of intentionally revealing functionality to a user and it's becoming an increasingly popular UX strategy as apps become more complex.

It depends on how complex your interface is. If there are lots of functionalities, then I would suggest to have a walkthrough. May be you could add a skip button, if they want to skip it. I would say it is an important step that you can take to avoid confusion which helps you to reduce support emails :)

Furthermore, [this article](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2010/11/dashboard-design-101.php) would help you to improve the usability of your dashboard.

Comment: You're welcome @RoshanAbraham :)